# How to get particular component of color in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

From the [p5 docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Color), it looks like there are methods to set components of color, but none to get them.

Given an object of class p5.Color, how do I get the red component of that color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `red()`, `blue()`, and `green()` functions.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).